# Settings on a Google form through GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I would like to ask you about Google apps script(GAS). I created a Google forms by importing questions from spreadsheet through GAS.

Now I would like to add the script below listed:
Make this a quiz --- true
Immediately after each submission

Respondent settings
Missed questions --- true
Correct answers---true
Point values--- true

Responses
Collect email addresses ---Responder input

How can I set these in the GAS in the spreadsheet?

[image]

This is the code I tried. (Generated from ChatGPT - because I don't have any ideas...)

```
function setQuizSettings() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  
  // Set the form as a quiz and show confirmation message after submission
  form.setIsQuiz(true);
  form.setConfirmationMessage("Thank you for taking the quiz!");
  
  // Set to require all questions to be answered and show correct answers after submission
  form.setAcceptingResponses(true);
  form.setRequired(true);
  form.setShowCorrectAnswers(true);
  
  // Set to collect email addresses
  form.setCollectEmail(true);
  
  // Set point values for each question
  var items = form.getItems();
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    if (item.getType() == FormApp.ItemType.GRID ||
        item.getType() == FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE ||
        item.getType() == FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX ||
        item.getType() == FormApp.ItemType.LIST ||
        item.getType() == FormApp.ItemType.SCALE) {
      item.asQuizItem()
          .setPointsPossible(1);
    }
  }
}

A
```

nd error message was
form.setAcceptingResponses(...).setMissedQuestions is not a function
I understand the error.
But I can't reach the script I really need...